# how to avoid collect when using Statistic.stat

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

when I calculate the Variance of my data, I have to collect first, Is there any other methods?

my data format:

```
1   2   3 
1   4   5
4   5   6
4   7   8
7   8   9
10  11  12
10  13  14
10  1   2
1   100 100
10  11  2
10  11  2
1   2   5
4   7   6
```

code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("hh")
conf.setMaster("local[3]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val data = sc.textFile("/home/hadoop4/Desktop/i.txt")
  .map(_.split("\t")).map(f => f.map(f => f.toDouble))
  .map(f => ("k"+f(0),f(1)))
//data:RDD[(String,Double)]
val dataArr = data.map(f=>(f._1,ArrayBuffer(f._2)))
//dataArr  RDD[(String,ArrayBuffer[Double])]

dataArr.collect().foreach(println(_))
//output
(k1.0,ArrayBuffer(2.0))
(k1.0,ArrayBuffer(4.0))
(k4.0,ArrayBuffer(5.0))
(k4.0,ArrayBuffer(7.0))
(k7.0,ArrayBuffer(8.0))
(k10.0,ArrayBuffer(11.0))
(k10.0,ArrayBuffer(13.0))
(k10.0,ArrayBuffer(1.0))
(k1.0,ArrayBuffer(100.0))
(k10.0,ArrayBuffer(11.0))
(k10.0,ArrayBuffer(11.0))
(k1.0,ArrayBuffer(2.0))
(k4.0,ArrayBuffer(7.0))


val dataArrRed = dataArr.reduceByKey((x,y)=>x++=y)
//dataArrRed :RDD[(String,ArrayBuffer[Double])]
dataArrRed.collect().foreach(println(_))
//output
(k1.0,ArrayBuffer(2.0, 4.0, 100.0, 2.0))
(k7.0,ArrayBuffer(8.0))
(k10.0,ArrayBuffer(11.0, 13.0, 1.0, 11.0, 11.0))
(k4.0,ArrayBuffer(5.0, 7.0, 7.0))

val dataARM = dataArrRed.collect().map(
f=>(f._1,sc.makeRDD(f._2,2)))
val dataARMM = dataARM.map(
f=>(f._1,(f._2.variance(),f._2.max(),f._2.min())))
.foreach(println(_))
sc.stop()

//output
(k1.0,(1777.0,100.0,2.0))
(k7.0,(0.0,8.0,8.0))
(k10.0,(18.24,13.0,1.0))
(k4.0,(0.8888888888888888,7.0,5.0))
```

//update ,now I calculate the second column and the third column at the same time and put them into an Array(f(1),f(2)), then turned into an RDD and aggregateByKey with it, the 'zero values' is Array(new StatCounter(),new StatCounter()),it has some problem.

```
val dataArray2 = dataString.split("\\n")
 .map(_.split("\\s+")).map(_.map(_.toDouble))
 .map(f => ("k" + f(0), Array(f(1),f(2))))
val data2 = sc.parallelize(dataArray2)
val dataStat2 = data2.aggregateByKey(Array(new StatCounter(),new 
StatCounter()))
({
(s,v)=>(
s(0).merge(v(0)),s(1).merge(v(1))
)
},{
(s,t)=>(
s(0).merge(v(0)),s(1).merge(v(1))
)})
```

it's wrong. Can I use `Array(new StatCounter(),new StatCounter())`? Thanks.

Comment: You completely lose the data of the third column, is that intended ?

Comment: There's a variety of basic statistics available in the http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions package. You could also use http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/util/StatCounter.html or http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer depending on your use case

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul yep but the format of the data does not make it easy to use them, that's the question of the OP. And look, he's already using `variance`. It's more a code cleaning question than a Spark one

Comment: Ah, misled by the wording of the question, then. It's not about having to use `collect` to use `variance`, but how to re-format the RDD to be able to use `variance` conveniently. So it seems still a Spark question, but really it's about `statsByKey`, should such a thing exist.

Comment: And `aggregateByKey` into a `StatsCounter` should do it.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Agreed, I was writing it as an answer

Comment: Me too, I'll let you continue, I'm supposed to be working :)

Comment: Yeah so am I. Not sure of my answer, let you check it when you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked example. It turns out to be a one-liner, and another line to map it into the OP's format.

Slightly different way of getting the data (more convenient for testing but same result)

```
val dataString = """1   2   3 
1   4   5
4   5   6
4   7   8
7   8   9
10  11  12
10  13  14
10  1   2
1   100 100
10  11  2
10  11  2
1   2   5
4   7   6  
""".trim

val dataArray = dataString.split("\\n")
 .map(_.split("\\s+")).map(_.map(_.toDouble))
 .map(f => ("k" + f(0), f(1)))
val data = sc.parallelize(dataArray)
```

Build the stats by key

```
val dataStats = data.aggregateByKey(new StatCounter())
                                    ({(s,v)=>s.merge(v)}, {(s,t)=>s.merge(t)})
```

Or, slightly shorter but perhaps over-tricky:

```
val dataStats = data.aggregateByKey(new StatCounter())(_ merge _, _ merge _)
```

Re-format to the OP's format and print

```
val result = dataStats.map(f=>(f._1,(f._2.variance,f._2.max,f._2.min)))
.foreach(println(_))
```

Output, same apart from some rounding errors.

```
(k1.0,(1776.9999999999998,100.0,2.0))
(k7.0,(0.0,8.0,8.0))
(k10.0,(18.240000000000002,13.0,1.0))
(k4.0,(0.888888888888889,7.0,5.0))
```

EDIT: Version with two columns

```
  val dataArray = dataString.split("\\n")
    .map(_.split("\\s+")).map(_.map(_.toDouble))
    .map(f => ("k" + f(0), Array(f(1), f(2))))
  val data = sc.parallelize(dataArray)

  val dataStats = data.aggregateByKey(Array(new StatCounter(), new StatCounter()))({(s, v)=> Array(s(0) merge v(0), s(1) merge v(1))}, {(s, t)=> Array(s(0) merge t(0), s(1) merge t(1))})

  val result = dataStats.map(f => (f._1, (f._2(0).variance, f._2(0).max, f._2(0).min), (f._2(1).variance, f._2(1).max, f._2(1).min)))
    .foreach(println(_))
```

Output

```
(k1.0,(1776.9999999999998,100.0,2.0),(1716.6875,100.0,3.0))
(k7.0,(0.0,8.0,8.0),(0.0,9.0,9.0))
(k10.0,(18.240000000000002,13.0,1.0),(29.439999999999998,14.0,2.0))
(k4.0,(0.888888888888889,7.0,5.0),(0.888888888888889,8.0,6.0))
```

EDIT2: "n"-column version

```
val n = 2

  val dataStats = data.aggregateByKey(List.fill(n)(new StatCounter()))(
      {(s, v)=> (s zip v).map{case (si, vi) => si merge vi}},
      {(s, t)=> (s zip t).map{case (si, ti) => si merge ti}})

  val result = dataStats.map(f => (f._1, f._2.map(x => (x.variance, x.max, x.min))))
    .foreach(println(_))
```

Output same as above, but if you have more columns, you can change `n`. It will break if the Arrays in any row has less than n elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  I'm green hand in Scala and Spark,and if I want to calculate the f(1),f(2) at the same time, the data's format is : `RDD[(String,Array[Double])]` , then `val datastats=data.aggregateByKey(Array(new StatCounter(),new StatCounter()))({(s,v)=>(s(0).merge(v(0)),s(1).merge(v(1)))},{(s,v)=>(s(0).merge(v(0)),s(1).merge(v(1)))})`, but it's error, what's wrong with it ? Thanks again.

Comment: What's the error? And please post this as a new question or an update to this one, a comment's too small for that.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question on Stack, and I have a lot to learn. I have already update the question now .Thanks :)

Comment: You were nearly there, you just needed to re-pack things into an array again. See my edit. A generalisation to `n` columns is pretty easy too

Comment: Thanks for your help.This's a big favor!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a stats object (class `StatCounter`). Then, I would :

- parse the file, split each line
- create the tuples and partition the RDD
- use aggregate by key and collect as an RDD of stat objects

Comment: "def
merge(other: StatCounter): StatCounter
Merge another StatCounter into this one, adding up the internal statistics"

Comment: Yep, but you cannot add a double to it. I would  have imagined something with a fine-grain control

Comment: Yes, you can :) there's an overloaded merge that adds a double to the counter. Seee my answer or the doc: "def
merge(value: Double): StatCounter
Add a value into this StatCounter, updating the internal statistics."

Comment: Oh yeah shit, I scanned the doc too fast. There was only a few methods and I missed it haha. The name of the method is not very good for what it does, it makes sense to merge two stats but with a single double... Thanks anyway, and +1

Comment: Thanks a lot :) and now I want to calculate the second column and the third column at the same time and it still has some error.Can I use `Array[(StatCounter,StatCounter)]` with aggregateByKey's 'zero value'? Thanks again.